BadGateway error while deploying azure webapp
In screenshot we can see the error of badgateway

I am facing this error while creating app functions also , give any suggestions to resolve this problem , Do i need to make any changes in Environmental variable or any other changes

Please provide more details about the issue. Are you using free subscription? What is the Run time stack of the app ? In which region you are trying to create the app?

This is the current issue which is seen in the Azure Free Trial Versions.

Even I got the same error while creating App Service.

I can see there is no option to raise a support ticket for free.




I have converted my free trial to pay-as-you go.

Now I can create all the resources without any issues.


App Service:

Function App:


Do i need to make any changes in Environmental variable or any other changes

AFAIK, we don't create or configure any Environment Variables while creating the app.
Refer MS Q&A which address the same issue.
